# Windows 10 - Scrolling vertically while dragging items into folders in Outlook

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook

I have a huge list of Folders in Outlook, and moving emails from the inbox into their designated folder takes forever when I use the traditional way of holding the pointer at the bottom of the scrollable list.

Is it possible to scroll a vertical list of items while dragging in Windows 10 using the scroll wheel on my mouse?

Answer (score 1):

You can't vertically scroll with the scroll wheel on the mouse while dragging a file, but you can achieve it by pointing your mouse at the buttons of the vertical scroll bar.

[Screenshot of vertical scrolling Downloads Folder while dragging a file from another folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOeOp.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite understand your request. But if you frequently move emails to a subfolder, you can create a rule to realize this.
Check this official article: [Manage email messages by using rules](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-email-messages-by-using-rules-c24f5dea-9465-4df4-ad17-a50704d66c59)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. The question is how to achieve vertical scrolling in windows while dragging something.

Answer (score 0):

I tried several shortcuts and did a little research. 
I think it's just not a feature. I figure in other application it works just fine, so it's not an issue with the mouse. 
Also looked into settings and didn't found anything.

So afaik the answer is no

Answer (score -1):

It doesnt seem to be a feature in Windows, but you can use the Program [AltDrag](https://stefansundin.github.io/altdrag/).
Download and run and then set the option `scroll inactive Windows` in the configuration:

image: [AltDrag Settings **Scroll inactive Window**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UgxB.png)